# crontabで毎日特定の時間(秒指定)に実行する方法

Tags: linux, unix, cron

crontabで毎日秒まで指定して特定の時間に実行するにはどうすればいいのでしょうか?

例えば、毎日 午前8時45分32秒ちょうどにジョブを実行したいときはどのように指定すればよいのでしょうか?

分単位では可能なようですが秒単位ではどのようにすればいいのでしょうか??

Comment: systemd を採用している Linux distribution であれば、CRON の代わりに systemd timer が利用可能で、`OnCalendar=*-*-* 8:45:32` などの設定が可能です。

Answer (score 5, accepted):

最初の処理に「sleep 32」を入れたシェルスクリプトを作ってそれを指定すればとりあえず実現できそうだと思います。

Answer (score 1):

秒単位の指定はできません。
代わりに `sleep 32; command` の様に crontab に書いてください。

```
#min hour day month week  command
45   8    *   *     *     sleep 32; command ...
```